# Perimeter of a 2D convex hull in Python

Tags: python, convex-hull

How can I calculate the perimeter of a convex hull in Python? I know `SciPy` has the `area` parameter for convex hulls; however, I need the `perimeter`.

Comment: Use SciPy to find the vertices of the convex hull, in order, then traverse the vertices and calculate the perimeter yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over the points of the convex hull and compute the distance between consecutive points:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.qhull import ConvexHull
from scipy.spatial.distance import euclidean

points = np.random.rand(30, 2)
hull = ConvexHull(points)

vertices = hull.vertices.tolist() + [hull.vertices[0]]
perimeter = np.sum([euclidean(x, y) for x, y in zip(points[vertices], points[vertices][1:])])
print(perimeter)
```

**Output**

```
3.11
```

**Note:** You also need to add the pair (last, first)

**UPDATE**

As an alternative, given that the data is 2D, you can use `hull.area`. That is the value returned in the above method is equal to the value of the area property. If you want the real **area**, you need to query `hull.volume`.

**Further**

1. [What is area in scipy convex hull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35664675/in-scipys-convexhull-what-does-area-measure)

Comment: I updated the answer, basically for 2D data `hull.area` returns the perimeter.

Comment: Interesting to see concepts are used differently in `Scipy`.