# Shapely Convex Hull area gives radically different results from scipy.ConvexHull area?

Tags: python, gis, shapely, scipy-spatial

I must be missing something incredibly obvious, but there seems to be a huge difference in the area computed by `scipy.ConvexHull.area` compared to `shapely.convex_hull.area`. I get

`Scipy Convex Hull Area: 457761.9061526276, Shapely Convex Hull Area: 13192154623.86528`

```py
from shapely.geometry import MultiPoint
from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull
import json


def convex_hull_compare():
    with open("./test_points.json", 'r') as f:
        points = json.load(f)
        print(points)
        hull = ConvexHull(points)
        ch_area = MultiPoint(points).convex_hull.area

        print(
            f"Scipy Convex Hull Area: {hull.area}, Shapely Convex Hull Area: {ch_area}")
        # Scipy Convex Hull Area: 457761.9061526276, Shapely Convex Hull Area: 13192154623.86528


if __name__ == "__main__":
    convex_hull_compare()
```

I've uploaded the `test_points.json` on a Github Gist [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/lieuzhenghong/22c2e2c994259e64114045b5857029b1/raw/91cdd489d3baf105183f5043bad4d03089171f14/test_points.json) and written a minimal version of the code for easy reproduction.

Comment: That does indeed! Thank you for linking the question.

Comment: If you'd like to answer the question and possibly explain why volume is area (and what area corresponds to with 2D points), I'll gladly accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A helpful commenter linked the [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35664675/in-scipys-convexhull-what-does-area-measure): the gist of it is that for 2D points, we want `ConvexHull.volume`, not `ConvexHull.area`.

This indeed gives us the right answer, but this is really confusing because the documentation doesn't mention this at all.

```py
from shapely.geometry import MultiPoint
from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull
import json


def convex_hull_compare():
    with open("./test_points.json", 'r') as f:
        points = json.load(f)
        print(points)
        hull = ConvexHull(points)
        ch_area = MultiPoint(points).convex_hull.area

        print(
            f"Scipy Convex Hull Area: {hull.area}, Shapely Convex Hull Area: {ch_area}")
        # Scipy Convex Hull Area: 457761.9061526276, Shapely Convex Hull Area: 13192154623.86528

        print(
            f"Scipy Convex Hull Area: {hull.volume}, Shapely Convex Hull Area: {ch_area}")
        #Scipy Convex Hull Area: 13192154623.865295, Shapely Convex Hull Area: 13192154623.86528


if __name__ == "__main__":
    convex_hull_compare()
```

Comment: The documentation does explain it: see my answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65660582/1048456